# CSS overflow and absolute positioning issue on Android Browser

Tags: android, css, cordova

We have a mobile web app built using JQuery Mobile, PhoneGap and ASP.net MVC.
The app is targeted to run on iOS and Android devices regardless of the browsers. 
We have tested the app on devices listed below and it seems to work fine without any issues

**iOS 5** - iPad , iPhone .

**Android 4.1.2** - Google Nexus 7, Samsung Galaxy S3, Samsung Galaxy Note 2, Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.

**Android 4.0.3** - Asus Transformer Tab

But when tested on **Android Stock browser** of **Samsung Galaxy Note 800** with 4.1.2, we encountered a very strange issue. The elements placed in a div (say child div) with css attribute'**overflow:auto**' do not respond to any touch events while scroll is enabled. The main thing to note here is that the Parent div containing this div is absolutely positioned '**position:abolute**'. After researching over the internet for sometime we found that the combination of absolute position and overflow attributes may cause some issues on Android browser.

Removing absolute position is not possible at the moment as it is resulting in complete redesign of the layouts and we are left with only few days for the release. So can any one suggest a quick fix for this?

Comment: I have the same issue. Any luck resolving it?

Answer (score 3):

Use `overflow-x` and/or `overflow-y` properties instead.

EG

```
overflow-y: scroll; /* allow vertical scrolling */
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* optional momentum scrolling */
```

Also, since scrollbars are hidden on touch devices you can use `:scroll` rather than `:auto`. It will look the same but may not be subject to the same bugs.

Comment: Worked for me after running a Cordova 5.4.1 app (cordova-android v4.1.1) with Android 4.1.2 SDK (Galaxy Note). Children containers are still a little laggy but thanks this works!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it worked, but adding -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; to your style will fix it

Comment: Adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` didn't worked for me =/... anyone knows how to fix this issue? I can't change the `position:absolute` of the parent container either.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with `overflow: auto` is/was a known issue in Android browser.
There was an issue reported on that in 2009 [(see here)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2118). I thought they had solved it in the meantime. It's marked obsolete. But people are still complaining it does not work. If it is so, I suspect they will not fix it anymore, as Chrome has become a standard Android browser now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript library called "iScroll". It works with most of Android devices and is not difficult to implement.
Just write `var scrollDiv = new iScroll('divId');` below the div element.
Here it is the project page: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to put the elements inside the absolutely positioned container in a new div and position it relatively?

```
<div class="absolutelyPositionedParent">
    <div class="relativelyPositionedElement"></div>
</div>

<style>.relativelyPositionedElement{position:relative;overflow:auto;}</style>
```