# overflow-y scrolling behavior with focused input/android keyboard popup

Tags: android, html, css

How does using the overflow property work with android mobile browsers? When you focus on an input, you cannot scroll to view content that goes behind the keyboard?

How do you fix this?

My sample is below:

```css
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999999;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.58);
}

.overlay-list {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <input type="text">
  <ul class="overlay-list">
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
   <li>This is a test item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
    <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
    <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
    <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
    <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
    <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I have a div thats fixed positioned over the viewport that is accompanied by a list. on iOS you can scroll and see what is behind the keyboard but on android the list goes behind the keyboard and you can't scroll to see it.

You can change `#overlay` to `absolute` which "fixes" it but the background stops at the end of the list, whereas I need to keep the background and be able to see the list on android.

The live codepen sample demonstrating the problem is below:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVWpzj/

How do you scroll behind the keyboard in a fixed position div in android?

I looked at: [CSS overflow and absolute positioning issue on Android Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938755/css-overflow-and-absolute-positioning-issue-on-android-browser)

And tried:

`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` but no go.